# Modify behavior of Spring @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I'm using Spring `@RolesAllowed` to secure my APIs (methods), but I'd like to change what happens when a method is called from an unauthorized user. The current behavior is that Spring throws an HTTP 403 error. This is great, but I would just like to add an additional error code in the body of the 403 response to be able to distinguish between access denied errors in different scenarios.

I'm having a hard time figuring out where the implementation of the `@RolesAllowed` annotation is located. Has anyone come across it? Or attempted to modify its behavior?

The methods in my controller currently look like the following:

```
@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_DEFENDANT", "ROLE_ADMIN"})
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{caseId}/owner")
public ResponseEntity<?> assignOwner(@PathVariable String caseId) {

    // method implementation

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is with an exception handler class and the @ExceptionHandler annotation.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleAccessDenied(HttpServletRequest request, AccessDeniedException ex) {

        // exception handling logic
        if (request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
            // user is not logged in
        } else {
            // user is logged in but doesn't have permission to the requested resource
        }

        // return whatever response you'd like
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, can be done without having to modify the annotation.

In your Spring config, you can specify an `AccessDeniedHandler` bean which will be called when Spring Security determines that your user is not allowed to perform the action that they've tried to perform.

The access denied handler is really simple:

```
public class CustomDefaultAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

An example of an `AuthenticationProvider` that gives you a bit more information about what failed would be:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        String username = String.valueOf(auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        String password = String.valueOf(auth.getCredentials());

        if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("You pudding, there is no username or password");
        } else {
            SystemUser user = userService.findByUsername(username);
            if(user == null){
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user exists, stop hacking");
            }
            //Do more stuff here to actually apply roles to the AuthToken etc
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually already had an AuthenticationFailureHandler. What I was missing is an AccessDeniedHandler. In your answer, you correctly mention AccessDeniedHandler, but then give an example of an AuthenticationFailureHandler. If you update the code sample to be accurate, I'll mark your answer as the chosen one.